# TomCat отправка сообщения на почту, проблема с кодировкой

Tags: java-ee, tomcat

Всем привет!
Отправляю сообщение на почту используя mailapi 1.4.7 на tomcat, на почту приходят кракозябры, если использовать русские буквы. Как сделать так, чтобы кракозябры не приходили? Как поменять кодировку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в кодировке, чтобы ее исправить нужно в файле server.xml, который находится в папке apache-tomcat-7.0.82\conf, добавить атрибут `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` в `Connector`

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            URIEncoding="UTF-8"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```